# Keep the UINavigationController while moving to next UIViewController but hide UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController` and in a `UITabBarController`.

When I select a row, I want to open my `UIViewController` in the `UINavigationController` but not in the `UITabBarController`.

When I create the `segue` from the cell to my `UIViewController` in the `Interface Builder`, I select `Show (eg. Push)`.

The problem is that it keeps the `UITabBarController` as well.

Then I tried the other kinds of segue but none of them display the `UINavigationController`.

I thought about adding `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` in `viewDidLoad()` and override `willMoveToParentViewController`:

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)

    if parent == nil {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
    }
}
```

It works fine except when I make a driven transition (paning from the edge to go back to the parent view controller).

How to do it the proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIViewController has a property named `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` which will do exactly what you want.

Just set `tableViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true` and you should be good to go!

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed)

Edit: if you're using Interface Builder to construct your views, there's actually a checkbox you can click, so you don't have to set it programmatically.

[image: screenshot of checkbox in interface builder]

Comment: Yes I just saw that. Best way to call it is by overriding `prepareForSegue` in the parent view controller. Calling it for example in `ViewDidLoad` of the child didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Oh -- if you have the view in Interface Builder, there's actually a checkbox in the attributes inspector. Select the view controller and you can see the checkbox in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/wBHDoca